# SQLAlchemy connection error with Db2 on IBM Cloud

Tags: python, db2, database-connection, ibm-cloud

I've been trying to connect to the IBM DB2 server hosted on IBM cloud using the provided credentials. I followed the instruction but i received following error :

> Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format, example:
>                  postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname
>                  or an existing connection: dict_keys([]) Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:ibm_db_sa Connection info needed in
>   SQLAlchemy format, example:
>                  postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname
>                  or an existing connection: dict_keys([])

Here is my code that i used :

```
# Remember the connection string is of the format:
# %sql ibm_db_sa://my-username:my-password@my-hostname:my-port/my-db-name
# Enter the connection string for your Db2 on Cloud database instance below
# i.e. copy after db2:// from the URI string in Service Credentials of your Db2 instance. Remove             the double quotes at the end.
%sql ibm_db_sa://user:password@dashdb-txn-sbox-yp-dal09-04.services.dal.bluemix.net:50000/BLUDB
```

I would appreciate if you help me with this error.

Comment: [see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74180001/13155046)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the IBM Cloud solution tutorial on [Combining serverless and Cloud Foundry for data retrieval and analytics](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/tutorials?topic=solution-tutorials-serverless-github-traffic-analytics). It uses Db2 and the [backend is written in Python and SQLAlchemy](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/github-traffic-stats/blob/master/backend/ghstats.py). The relevant part [starts in line 78](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/github-traffic-stats/blob/master/backend/ghstats.py#L78):

```
if dbInfo['port']==50001:
    # if we are on the SSL port, add additional parameter for the driver
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']=dbInfo['uri']+"Security=SSL;"
else:
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']=dbInfo['uri']
```

The code reads the URI from the credentials variable in the Cloud Foundry environment. If the port is 50001, it uses SSL/TLS for encrypting the connection and you need to add `Security=SSL` to that URI.

Also, make sure that your code has the [Db2 modules for SQLAlchemy](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdbsa/tree/master/ibm_db_sa) installed. See [requirements.txt](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/github-traffic-stats/blob/master/backend/requirements.txt) for the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
!pip install --upgrade ibm_db
!pip install --upgrade ibm_db_sa
!pip install --upgrade SQLAlchemy

import ibm_db
import ibm_db_sa
import sqlalchemy

%load_ext sql
```

And then:

```
%sql ibm_db_sa://user:password@dashdb-txn-sbox-yp-dal09-04.services.dal.bluemix.net:50000/BLUDB
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues. Here is what worked for me:

Try to install the SQLAchemy version 1.4 before you run the SQL using

`pip install --upgrade 'SQLAlchemy<1.4'`

Be sure to install the IBM DB2 Python Libraries as follows:

`!pip install --force-reinstall ibm_db ibm_db_sa`

Answer (score 0):

!pip uninstall sqlalchemy==1.4 -y && pip install sqlalchemy==1.3.24

%load_ext sql

Use this prior to running your query and your query will work.